# Calling C# from F# -- Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException

Tags: c#, f#, mono

Anyone any ideas in calling c# function from f# code.

I have a c# function like so

```
public class VehicleDetailsBridge
{

    public void SaveVehicle(long id)
    {
         var db = "test call";
     }
}
```

then in f# I have:

```
type Persistence as this =
    member x.SaveToDatabase(LatestVid)
    let b = VehicleDetailsBridge()
    b.SaveVehicle(LatestVid)
```

I have a reference to C# class library in my F# project.

However when i run this code i get the below exception in Xamarin:

> Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedExecption

Comment: FWIW, given the corrected syntax provided by Patrick McDonald, I can't reproduce this issue in Visual Studio on Windows... I set up a C# library project and referenced it from an F# console project and called the `Persistance` class from `Main`. No problems. It's tempting to conclude that the issue is related to a particular Mono environment...

Answer (score 2):

```
type Persistence() =                         // need braces here, and not 'as this'
    member x.SaveToDatabase(latestVid) =
        let b = VehicleDetailsBridge()       // indent the method body
        b.SaveVehicle(latestVid)
```

My full F# program is as follows:

```
open FsCsInterop

type Persistence() =                         // need braces here, and not 'as this'
    member x.SaveToDatabase(latestVid) =
        let b = VehicleDetailsBridge()       // indent the method body
        b.SaveVehicle(latestVid)
        printfn "Saved %d" latestVid

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let p = Persistence()
    p.SaveToDatabase(2L)
    0

// Prints "Saved 2"
```

Comment: still same error at the moment can you reference c# from f#

Comment: breaking when trying to instantiate

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, am at home now and tried it on Xamarin on a Mac and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let b = VehicleDetailsBridge() // create instance of class
b.SaveVehicle(LatestVid)
```

VehicleDetailsBridge is a class so you need to open this as a class.